# Cause of R package not loading quietly?

Tags: r, package, loading, plyr, suppress-warnings

Sometimes when you load a new package in R there is a message printed. There are built-in arguments in functions `library` and `require` to prevent this form happening, namely "verbose" and "quietly." (see [here](http://127.0.0.1:28007/library/base/html/library.html)).

However, I cannot get the package 'plyr' to load without a message. I have tried setting `quitely = TRUE` and `verbose = FALSE` (and the combination of the two) but I still get this following result:

```
library(plyr,quietly = T,verbose = F)
Warning message:
package ‘plyr’ was built under R version 2.15.3
```

I've also tried using `suppressMessages()`, but still got the same result.

Any ideas of how to suppress this warning message?

Comment: Looks like a warning. What about `suppressWarnings`? Or reinstalling the package...

Comment: @Dason Duh. Yup, that worked! Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a warning to me.  Wrap the call in `supressWarnings` to prevent the warning from being printed. Or reinstall the package to get rid of the warning entirely.